# Linux - regularily moving directory contents

Tags: linux, cron, file-transfer

Collaboration partners of our company will upload files (typically a few GB in size) to a directory on one of our external servers.
From that directory, I will move them to our internal network, where they will be ultimately consumed by our analysts.

So far, the upload is solved with a chroot jail and works fine, same for for what happens when the files arrive in our internal network.

The transfer to our internal network, however, is problematic. I simply rsync them with --remove-source-files and a find to delete the empty directories.
Thing is, the cron job polling interval on the directory needs to be low (we'd prefer every minute), while the transfer time is fairly high (our office DSL is slow), and obviously we don't want to start uploading the same file every 5 minutes.
Is there a good solution for this problem? I could move the contents to a temporary directory, and then rsync from there, but I'm feeling like a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: As a minor-aside, how are you synchronising the partner<->server side of things i.e. how do you ensure that you don't start rsyncing-and-deleting before they've finished uploading?

Comment: That's part of the upload script I prepared for them - they upload to `dir a`, then when the upload is done, the script will move that do `dir b`, which is the watched dir. Since this is a move on the same partition, it's nearly instantaneous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lockrun](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/lockrun.html) was designed specifically for this use case:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * lockrun --lockfile=/tmp/.partner-sync -- rsync src/ dest/
```

That will trigger every minute but only run if `/tmp/.partner-sync` is not already locked.

Comment: And, if you have problem with bandwitdth, you can use `--bwlimit` switch for rsync...

Comment: I think this almost-but-not-quite solves the problem. I think the OP is hoping that if `file2` is ready to sync whilst `file1` is still syncing, then the transfer of `file2` will start immediately (rather than "on the next poll after `file1` has finished")

Comment: @nickgrim This is actually perfect, if file2 were to start rsyncing immediately, it would just congest our pipes, meaning file1 would be finished much later.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) simply because lockrun (which Darren Chamberlain mentioned) does not have a maintained deb package.